# ElasticSearch search results change between invocations

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch

I have ~ 6 million documents in my index. When I make a search query, I get two different hit count values between invocations.

Meaning, the count is x for 5 invocations and y for the next 5 invocations and then it goes back to x and keeps cycling between x and y.

Can someone explain this behavior and what I might be doing wrong? Here's the query

```
    query = {"query" : {"match" : {"name" : "value"}}}
    response = es.search(index="my_index",doc_type="my_type",body=query)
```

Comment: Have you check if for both cases all shards worked fine?

Comment: How should I determine that? Should I look at the value of 'shards' I get back in the response?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would do in first place. You should get info about successful and failed shards. Also maybe query `explain` will show something

Comment: Specifying a shard preference (in my case ?preference=_primary) resolve although I don't yet understand the reason

Comment: Maybe some of replicas are corrupted?